# Speical symbol is coming in x-axis in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I am getting special symbol in `x-axis` while generating chart. i am not able to figure out the issue.my actual string "Employee engagement scores of team or division of individuals after coaching".please suggest me.

My Implemented code: http://jsfiddle.net/sameekmishra/kzcxez3z/2/

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: I am not able to recreate your issue. What browser are you using? Is your website support UTF-8? Additionally you have added a lot of code that is not connected with your issue. It is good practice to show jsFiddle only with necessary code, so it will be simple to investigate where the problem is. Here you can find minified example: http://jsfiddle.net/kzcxez3z/4/ And here you can find topic that looks related to your issue: http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/data-label-truncation-bug-related-to-encoding-of-ellipsis-t32965/

Comment: I have tested on IE,chrome,Firefox(latest version) and all are showing same chart view,might be on my side chart rendering side by side then this issue came into picture,right now i am also not able to replicate same issue on Jsfiddle.Is any limitation for showing the categories in x-axis?

Comment: If your label is to big, it should show ellipsis instead of whole label string. Here you can find information how you can disable this functionality: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.style

Comment: Thanks, but it's client requirement to show full label but i am getting strange behavior :)

Comment: So if you would like to show full label, you may use textOverflow: 'none' and it should help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this. (This is to add ellipsis inside xAxis)



 xAxis: [{
     labels: {
         formatter: function () {
             var formatted;
             if (this.value.length > 35) {
                 formatted = this.value.substring(0, 30) + "..." + this.value.substring(this.value.length - 10);

             } else {
                 formatted = this.value;
             }
             return '<div class="js-ellipse" style="width:226; overflow:hidden" title="' + this.value + '">' + formatted + '</div>';
         },
         style: {
             width: '226'
         },
         useHTML: true
     }
}],
```

Hope this helps :)